# Passive equalizer design

Tags: amplifier, filter, design

I have circuit feeded from a 3.5 mm jack through a JFET common-drain buffer then i need the filter this audio input to pass bandwith 400-19600 Hz. I can do this with RC bandpass filter but then I need an adjustable equalizer design that can amplify higher or lower frequencies as user wish. I try to do it with cascaded bandpass filter, second filter resistances are potentiometers so they are adjustable but gain is dropped drastically and second filter interferes first one so that first bandpass frequencies changed any idea how can I design or fix this kind of circuit? After equalizer circuit, adjusted frequency range audio goes into an BJT amplifier to the speaker which is the purpose. I need help with especially equalizer part.

Comment: Even a simple bass and treble tone controls circuit is active with an opamp, not passive. A midrange 3rd band can be added. Many car equalizers use 5 bands. Fairly high quality equalizers use 10 octave bands. Professional equalizers use 23 third octave bands. Each band uses an opamp and a cut/boost pot.

Comment: Suppose you make three such passive filters: LP, BP, HP. How do you plan on summing them up?